# Ideal practice for implementing a 1:1 relationship

Tags: database, database-design

In a webshop, there are two (relevant to this question) tables: `UserSnapshot` and `Purchase`. Upon making a purchase, the user's current information is snapshot so that the purchase records are intact even if the user is later removed or changed. This gives a 1:1 relationship, where each purchase has only one user snapshot, and each user snapshot has only one purchase.

My question is, how should I implement this? Should I have a foreign key pointing to the user snapshot in the purchase table, the other way around, or should I use both (redundant)? Should I combine the two (messy)? Serialise the user snapshot (does not obey 'one value per field')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the likely queries you want to run, and design your model on that basis.

For instance, I guess you want to know "which orders has this customer placed?". The most natural way of expressing that would be something like:

```
select *
from customer c
inner join customer_snapshot cs
  on c.customer_id = cs.customer_id
inner join orders o
  on cs.order_id = o.order_id
```

where c.customer_id = ?

Or: "What is the current status of the customer who placed this order?".

```
select *
from order o
inner join customer_snapshot cs
  on o.order_id = cs.order_id
inner join customer c
  on cs.customer_id = c.customer_id
where o.order_id = ?
```

This feels natural to me, as it almost uses the customer_snapshot table as a "many to many" joining table.

But that's mostly stylistic - the join could just as easily be on `o.customer_snapshot_id = cs.customer_snapshot_id`.

How about "how many orders were sent to customers living in city x?"

```
select *
from order o
inner join customer_snapshot cs
  on o.order_id = cs.order_id
inner join customer c
  on cs.customer_id = c.customer_id
and cs.city = ?
```

You don't need "redundant" columns - all queries work without jumping through hoops. You *could* serialize the snapshot data, but then the "which orders were for customers living in city x" query would be painful.

Comment: This seems like the most level-headed and, I'd guess, performant approach to this problem. Thank you! On a side note, you missed a space in the first code block's last row, but I can't propose an edit without at least six characters edited.